# Create nested directory in Application Support in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file-manager

Trying to create a nested directory within Application Support and it's failing. The error message I get is `"You don’t have permission to save the file 'folder1' in the folder 'testApp'`.

```
    let path = getApplicationSupportDirectory()
    let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as! String
    let folder = path.appendingPathComponent("\(appName)/folder1", isDirectory: true)
    print("[ERR]: Folder location: \(folder.relativePath)")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folder.relativePath) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folder.relativeString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("[ERR]: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
    }
```

Folder location outputs the correct location and it appears to create the first directory within "appName".

Comment: What is `getApplicationSupportDirectory()` returning? Try replacing it with `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!`? You need to have write-permission for the folder you try to write to...

Comment: @Michael - getApplicationSupportDirectory() returns the absoluteURL for the application support directory. How to enable write permissions on a new folder?

Comment: Basically do not use `relativePath / relativeString` for file system URLs. Just use the `path` property. And apart from `fileExists` it's recommended to use always the URL related API anyway.

Comment: @vadian - changed to `path` and still the issue.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is perfectly valid and relates to the creation of a nested directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this code, it's supposed to work.

It uses the API of `FileManager` to create the Application Support folder if it does not exist.

```
do {
    let applicationSupportFolderURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as! String
    let folder = applicationSupportFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("\(appName)/folder1", isDirectory: true)
    print("[ERR]: Folder location: \(folder.path)")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folder.path) {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folder, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked after some safe checking on the try block. Any reason why the `FileManager.default.urls()` didn't work?

Comment: This API does not create the directory if it's missing.